# Clone javascript object and update the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have a problem with the logic to update the values in a json.
Initial json is

```
var val = {
    "data": [
      {x: 1396328400000, y: 92, num: "243"},          
      {x: 1425189600000, y: 91, num: "158"}              
    ]
};
```

I want to duplicate `data` into another object `data1` containing this in val.
Considering current month is March 2015, `timeInMilliSeconds` will give the value as `1425189600000`, If the code encounters this value, it should replace the `num` in first `data` array to `0`. Except the `1425189600000` in `data1` all the values should be `0`

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63Lwac0x/5/)

```
var date = new Date();
    timeInMilliSeconds = Date.parse(date.getFullYear() + "/" +(date.getMonth()+1));

val = {
    "data": [
      {x: 1396328400000, y: 92, num: "243"},          
      {x: 1425189600000, y: 91, num: "0"}              
    ],
    "data1": [ 
      {x: 1396328400000, y: 92, num: "0"},          
      {x: 1425189600000, y: 91, num: "158"}
    ]
};
```

Comment: @Bergi sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I also wonder if your example data is a bit too large. Can you trim it down to an object with only 2-3 values and explain a little clearer (a) what you're trying to make happen and (b) what's not working about your current code? You haven't actually posted any code (to show what you've tried)...

Comment: Could it be that `typeof timeInMilliSeconds` is an object but you are comparing to a number?

Comment: @brianvaughn Please see the update. I am having trouble to loop through the keys and update the num value to `0` as i encounter them in `data1`

Comment: @brianvaughn I have updated the `fiddle`, I have arrived at half the solution.

Comment: I don't see any json in your question/code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you just need to update your check to make sure you're casting to a number:

```
if(k == 'num' && parseInt(val.data[prop]['x']) == timeInMilliSeconds) {
```